# Получить html через webview

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

У меня есть публичная папка на яндекс диске — `https://disk.yandex.ru/d/AKKeLJ7SeMPsrg`

Фотографии там подгружаются скриптами `js` на сколько я понял, поэтому если просто отправить `get` запрос, то результат будет без картинок.

Но, `WebView` выполняет эти скрипты и всё успешно отображает, но я хотел — удалить лишние элементы страницы и оставить только `div` с картинками, но для этого необходимо получить `html` код уже загруженной страницы, сделать это я пытался так:

```
<WebView x:Name="webView" Navigated="WebView_Navigated" />

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    var url = "https://disk.yandex.ru/d/l-OceLgwqfeuLA";
    webView.Source = new UrlWebViewSource { Url = url };
}

async void WebView_Navigated(Object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    var html = await webView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML");

    html = Regex.Replace(html, @"\\[Uu]([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})", m => char.ToString((char)ushort.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)));
    html = Regex.Unescape(html);

    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(html);
 }
```

В итоге в методе `WebView_Navigated` в переменную `html` получаю исходный код страницы, но он явно какой-то битый, то есть скрипты выполнены с ошибкой, вот отрывок результата:

```
!function(n,i){if(n.Ya=n.Ya||{},Ya.Rum)throw new Error("Rum: interface is already defined");
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разобраться? Почему `WebView` нормально показывает результат, но если получить его исходный код, то он такой как выше?

Comment: Если вы видите, что сайт получает данные неким "тайным" образом, через JS, то первым делом пытайтесь найти источник, от куда он берет эти данные, а **не** рьяно бегите брать первый попавшийся браузер, чтоб он сделал всю работу за вас. Не ленитесь! Допустим указанная вами ссылка, открываем в браузере, смотртим HTML и видим там `<script type="application/json" id="store-prefetch">`, который содержит огромный JSON со всеми данными, которые на странице, а вот [ваши изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MuKW.png), с размерами id, даже ссылка есть в `meta` разделе.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо большое за помощь! Я всё на вкладке network в браузере рылся, а оказалось всё намного ближе, просто я в этом не очень разбираюсь, спасибо.